# Weird characters when I print a number into a file (bash shell)

Tags: bash, shell, printf, echo

I have this line in my script.sh

```
printf "%d" "$endMS_line"
```

$endMS_line is a number. I get that number with

```
endMS_line=`cat file | awk '{if($1=='"$variable"') print NR}'`
```

And to print it I use

```
printf "%d" "$endMS_line"
```

or

```
echo $endMS_line
```

So everything works perfectly in the standard output. The problem is when I want to save that number into a file (because I want to use the result in another script, may be there is a clever way to do it than write a file and then read the number from the file, etc..)

But for now I am trying to do that. How? Well I write this in the standard output.

```
myscript.sh inputs > file.txt
```

But when I try to see the file (when I open the file) I see the result plus weird characteres

```
[H[2J867
```

The correct number in this example is 867. Anyone know how can I fix this?
Thank you!

Comment: I think you mean `endMS_line=\`awk '$1'=="$variable"'{print NR}' file\` `

Comment: Could the problem just be you're not adding a newline after the number? Does `printf '%d\n' "$endMS_line"` make a difference?

Comment: William if I keep the "clear" command at the begginning of the script, doesnt work your solution =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the begginning of the script I had the command:

```
clear
```

removing that and using:

```
echo "$endMS_line"
```

Then in the standard output:

```
myscript.sh input > file.txt
```

works perfectly.